# How to handle bitmaps in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, bitmap

I need to draw a basic shapes on my bitmap (Bgra32). However, RenderTargetBitmap works with Pbgra32 bitmaps. What is the most elegant way of dealing with bitmaps in WPF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a BitmapSource with any format you like in the constructor itself and then send a byte array with the drawing you want. For example:

```
 byte[] pixelData = DrawYourPicture();

 int stride = width * PixelFormats.Pbgra32.BitsPerPixel/8;
 BitmapSource bmpSource = BitmapSource.Create(width, height, 96, 96,
                PixelFormats.Pbgra32, null, pixelData, stride);
```

The bmpSource can then be directly assigned to the Source property of an Image.